# Render view in ajax request translate lang error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, translation

I have a partial `(partial/article.blade.php)` .. i make ajax request to this controller action and i return this view as response

i'm using this code in my controller action :

```
return View::make('partial.article')
        ->with('articles',$articles);
```

partial.article :

```
{{ Lang::get('messages.title') }}
    @foreach ($articles as $article)
        $article->title               
    @endforeach
```

The problem is in the translated word {{ Lang::get('messages.by') }} he print it like that in view it doesn't inerpreat it .. but when i use the partial without ajax request it show the word translated correctly .

Comment: Does the foreach work as expected?

Comment: Yes it works fine

Comment: And if you go to the url of ajax request (the one that returns the rendered view) does it render `Lang::get('stuff')` there?

Comment: yes it give somentings like that : messages.title title1 title2 ...